# We have $N\unlhd G$, a cyclic subgroup of order $n$, $G/N$ cyclic group of order $m$ s.t. $\gcd(m,\phi(n))=1$. Show $G$ is abelian.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, totient-function, quotient-group

Problem statement:

> We have $N \trianglelefteq G$ a normal cyclic subgroup of order $n$, $G/N$ cyclic group of order $m$ such that $\gcd(m, \phi(n)) = 1$, where $\phi$ is the Euler function. Show that $G$ is abelian.

My thoughts:

1. Take the generators $aN$ of $G/N$ and $x$ of $N$. Now if we can show that $ax = xa$, then we are done.
2. $\phi(n)$ seems to be pointing to the size of set of generators in $N$. But I am stuck here...

Comment: Do you know about semidirect products?  In that context, you need to show that there's only one semidirect product of $G/N$ acting on $N$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring So we have $G/N \to Aut(N)$. Now note that $N$ a cyclic group makes $Aut(N)$ a cyclic group of size $\phi(n)$. By gcd and order constraints, we the generator of $G/N$ (call it $a$ here has to be mapped to the identity automorphism, i.e. $a^{-1}xa = x$, and we are done.

Comment: @BrianMoehring One thing though...Are there theorems that tell us $G/N \rtimes N$ can produce $G$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring I guess it is just a different definition (using exact sequence $1 \to N \to G \to G/N \to 1$) than the normal one: 1. $NH = G$ 2. $N \cap H = {e}$. Is that correct?

Comment: Actually, you have me doubting it now.  It looks like we might need Schur-Zassenhaus to conclude $G$ is even a semidirect product of $N$ and $G/N$ to start with, and we don't necessarily have $\gcd(m,n) = 1$... I'll leave my comments to give some context, but as it stands, I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The group $G$ acts by conjugation on $N$. This yields a homomorphism $f:G\to\mathrm{Aut}(N)\cong(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$. Since $N$ is abelian, $N$ is contained in the kernel of $f$. By hypothesis, $|G/N|=m$ and $|(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times|=\phi(n)$ are coprime. Hence, $\ker f=G$, i.e. $N$ is contained in the center of $G$. Now you can use your first argument to show that $G$ is abelian.